# How can I format data.message in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on an application where I'm providing a list of issues in the data.message on a bad request.

The issue that I'm running into is I would like to add a line break after each error to make it look better.  I tried to do a string replace and that didn't work.  I also tried to add a "
" to each message.  Unfortunately, that didn't work and it just outputed the break tags.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

This is how I'm outputting the message:

{{::serviceError.data.message}}

I've tried to add break tags and /n to the message to get it to work.

Comment: We'll need to see some code to understand what the problem is

Comment: I added some code to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!

Put this in your directive:

```
$scope.$watch("serviceError.data.message",
    function () {
        if ($scope.serviceError != null) {
            var errorstring;

            $scope.serviceError.data.message.split('.');
            var formatedlist = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < errorstring.length; i++) {
                formatedlist += errorstring[i] + ".</br>";
            }

            $scope.errorList = formatedlist;     
         }
     });
```

Put this in your html:

```
<div ng-bind-html="errorList"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand very well, but i'll try to answer your question. If you have a list of issues like this:

```
let issues = ['issue', 'issue', 'issue', 'issue'];
```

To print it, breaking the lines, you can try this:

```
issues = issues.map(issue => issue + '\n').toString();
```

Comment: This is currently my angularjs code: {{::serviceError.data.message}} I tried to add the <br/> tag to each issue. Unfortunately, the break tags appeared in the output and it wasn't doing the line break.

Comment: Try use _template literals_ (`issue`) instead of single quotes ('issue').

Answer (score 0):

Did you try add "\n" at the end of the string (or <\br> tag if you can use HTML tags)?

Comment: This is currently my angularjs code:

{{::serviceError.data.message}}

I tried to add the <br/> tag to each issue.  Unfortunately, the break tags appeared in the output and it wasn't doing the line break.

Comment: what about adding  "\n" at the end of the string?